# sklearn classification_report ValueError: Unknown label type:

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, keras

I am trying a simple classification report on the output from a Keras model prediction. The format of the inputs are two 1D arrays, but the error is still thrown.

```
    Y_pred = np.squeeze(model.predict(test_data[0:5]))
    classification_report(test_labels[0:5], Y_pred)


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-235-49afd2f46d17> in <module>()
----> 1 classification_report(test_labels[0:5], Y_pred)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.pyc in classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels, target_names, sample_weight, digits)
   1356 
   1357     if labels is None:
-> 1358         labels = unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
   1359     else:
   1360         labels = np.asarray(labels)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.pyc in unique_labels(*ys)
     97     _unique_labels = _FN_UNIQUE_LABELS.get(label_type, None)
     98     if not _unique_labels:
---> 99         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))
    100 
    101     ys_labels = set(chain.from_iterable(_unique_labels(y) for y in ys))

ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([-0.38947693,  0.18258421, -0.00295772, -0.06293461, -0.29382696]), array([-0.46586546,  0.1359883 , -0.00223112, -0.08303966, -0.29208803]))
```

Both of the inputs are of the same type, so I am confused why this would not work?  I have tried changing the type explicitly to dtype=float and flattening the inputs, but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you include the shape of both `test_labels` and `Y_pred` please?

Comment: is it a classification problem or a regression problem?

Comment: The array shown in the last line of the error shows your `y`. Which in my opinion is continuous. So classification type methods or estimators will not work on it. Because this is Regression problem

Comment: If you are using the MNIST tutorial, its a classification problem. But your y values as seen in the error do not correspond to that. You should check the y values that they are actually what you want them to be (labels of output class). And preferable put the whole code here, so that its easy to debug.

Comment: It is a regression problem, you were right and that I am trying to use classifcaiton_report for regression which will not work.

Answer (score 3):

`classification_report` works only for classification problems.

If you have a classification problem (eg, binary), use the following

```
Y_pred = np.squeeze(model.predict(test_data[0:5]))
threshold = 0.5
classification_report(test_labels[0:5], Y_pred > threshold)
```

`threshold` will make everything greater than 0.5 (in example above), 1.0

Comment: Thank you, I am now recieving the error 

`'ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed, got types set(['binary', 'continuous'])"`


I was following the tutorial from this [page](https://github.com/julienr/ipynb_playground/blob/master/keras/convmnist/keras_cnn_mnist.ipynb), and they seem to be able to do what I originally wanted to do.